# Staying overnight in Abu Dhabi airport

Tags: layovers, hotels, stopovers, abu-dhabi, etihad

I'm flying from JFK to COK through AUH. My flight is with Etihad and has an 8-hour layover in Abu Dhabi. I didn't know about their free stopover program, and it seems like the layover is too short to qualify. Does anyone know anywhere I can sleep within the airport terminal? Are there any hotels that I can access without "exiting" the airport? Will an Etihad boarding pass give me discounts for these?

Answer (score 5):

sleepinginairports.net is a great resource that does just what it says on the tin. [Here's their page for Abh Dhabi](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/abu-dhabi-airport-guide.htm).

Oddly for a major airport, Abu Dhabi does *not* appear to have any transit (within security/immigration) hotels at time of writing. Aerotel used to operate them in T1 and T3, but they're not listed on the [official site](https://www.myaerotel.com/en-uk) anymore.