# Resting in Abu Dhabi airport

Tags: minors, lounges, abu-dhabi, auh

Me and my friend are traveling from JFK to COK and have an 8-ish hour layover at Abu Dhabi. I would prefer to sleep for jet lag reasons. Any recommendations for lounges or sleeping areas?

Comment: You might start by visting [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net), and reviewing this -nine-years-old [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/sleeping-options-for-9-hour-stop-over-at-abu-dhabi-international-airport?rq=1).

Comment: See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185668/staying-overnight-in-abu-dhabi-airport#185689